# Informix: datetime manipulation

Tags: datetime, informix

I have 2 fields in a table test1:

```
onlydate DATE
onlytime DATETIME HOUR TO MINUTE
```

and 1 field in a table test2:

```
dateandtime DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND
```

Now I need to append the value of onlydate and onlytime field and set it to dateandtime field.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 4):

The basic issues are:

1. Converting DATE to DATETIME -- use EXTEND.
2. Converting DATETIME to INTERVAL -- use subtraction.

Assembling these two concepts and applied to SELECT only:

```
create temp table td(dateonly date not null, timeonly datetime hour to minute);
insert into td values('2010-05-31', '06:30');
select extend(dateonly, year to second) + 
       (timeonly - datetime(00:00) hour to minute) from td;
```

The result is what you want:

```
DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND
2010-05-31 06:30:00
```

Subtracting midnight from `timeonly` converts it into an INTERVAL HOUR TO MINUTE; you can add a DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND and an INTERVAL HOUR TO MINUTE, getting a DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND.  You cannot add two DATETIME values.

So, strictly answering your question, you'd write:

```
INSERT INTO Test2(DateAndTime)
     SELECT EXTEND(DateOnly, YEAR TO SECOND) + 
                  (TimeOnly - DATETIME(00:00) HOUR TO MINUTE) AS DateAndTime
       FROM Test1;
```

(I run with DBDATE=Y4MD- so that the date literal shown works as expected.  To insert the DATE constant reliably regardless of the setting of DBDATE, use `MDY(5,31,2010)`.)

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate both values as text, and cast it to datetime like:

```
update datetime_test
   set dateandtime = (dateonly || ' ' || timeonly || ':00')::
                      datetime year to second
```

Comment: Your solution works nicely when the columns are all in one table, and `DBDATE='Y4MD-'`.  When the values have to be transferred between tables, you probably end up using an INSERT or MERGE statement.  When DBDATE is set to other formats (e.g. `DBDATE=DMY4/` or `DBDATE=MDY4/`) then the formatting done on the dateonly to convert it to a string means it cannot be converted back to DATETIME.  The format requirements for the cast are strict.